# How to set a label for single mapbox marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Hey guys I know that we can set labels for the markers using the map.add layer method. But is there any possibility of setting the label for a Mapbox marker in the following method ( eg Set label or something)?
Or is there any possibility that I can use a javascript function to attach a label to this marker? Thanks a lot for your time.

```
var mymarker= new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
.setPopup(
  new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>' )
).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score -4):

You're confusing [Popups](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup), [Markers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker) and [Symbol layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol).

Suggest you read the documentation closely to understand how each works.

Comment: hey i was using symbol layers before when  had a lot of markers. Now its just one marker and i trying to set a label for it using set method. Hoping map box had something like SET label or something.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately i found nothing on that.

Comment: This is not an answer. Should have been a comment.